# Filtering on datetime field works different for SELECT and DELETE

Tags: sql, datetime, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have following code:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab (
  create_time datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (create_time)
);

INSERT INTO test_tab (create_time) VALUES ('2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000000');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM test_tab WHERE create_time = '2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000000';
DELETE FROM test_tab WHERE create_time = '2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000000';
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM test_tab WHERE create_time = '2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000000';
```

Both selects return one row. Any clues why it might happen?

$ mysql --version mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/T3Jw_apG) supports this claim.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have more than 6 microseconds, so you need to convert it first

for the select, it automatically converts it, which the DELETE doesn't

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab (
  create_time datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (create_time)
);

INSERT INTO test_tab (create_time) VALUES ('2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000000');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM test_tab WHERE create_time = '2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000000';
```

| create_time |
| --- |
| 2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000 |

```
DELETE FROM test_tab 
  WHERE create_time = STR_TO_DATE('2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000000','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f');
```

```
SELECT * FROM test_tab WHERE create_time = '2023-04-21 00:17:24.000000000';
```

| create_time |
| --- |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-WMIp-QC)

Comment: This is unsettling, as this behaviour is put on display due to an external software which I can barely modify. I hoped that a configuration change (or setting something on driver connection/connection session) could solve the problem.

Comment: Even if I insert without the precision of 9 digits, the issue still remains.

Comment: no you must use str_to_date, there is no other solution for mariadb, as it will only support 6 digits is tried to change the digits to a numbe rhiger than 6 and it will not work.